# How do I add project to the build path in Android Studio (Gradle) without actually exporting it on the final APK?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

Hello everyone and thanks for your patience, I'm in the process of migrating projects from Eclipse to Android Studio.

I have a project where a few of its classes are loaded in runtime with reflection. Those classes sometimes use a library that is located in the main process where the reflected class is being loaded, because it needs its particular version of the class. It is more or less a plugin architecture.

In Eclipse this is fairly easy to achieve. I just have to remove the android library in the plugin project, add it to the build path and uncheck the exported project, all from the project settings.

How can I do this with Gradle? The only way I know of adding library projects is this one, but this one is the regular one and exports the classes. I just want them to be there at build time.

```
dependencies { compile project(':someLibrary') }
```